# Python, Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

i'm trying to scrape a web page, i get the result that i want but it seams that i can't get it into excel. I'm new at this so be gentle :)
i'm using BeautifulSoup library to try to get the result into excel, but when i try this, i get into excel the following result:`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7b02ef38780a9a4a510ac221c77d19ee"`
here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
chrome_path = r"F:\Python\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/franta/ligue-1/meciuri/")
main = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="fs-fixtures"]/table[1]/tbody""")
filename="lista campionate.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
for primary in main:
    home_team = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="g_1_8ClzUOIT"]/td[3]""")
    away_team = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="g_1_8ClzUOIT"]/td[4]""")
    print(primary_text)
    f.write(str(primary))
f.close()
```

PS: i'm sorry about the romanian tags that are into the code
Thank you

Comment: Seems like your code is missing few statements. For example you are printing `primary_text` but haven't assigned it to anything in your snippet. Also `home_team` and `away_team` lists remain unused. You shouldn't be writing WebElements to the excel but instead extracting the attributes associated with them using `.text` property or `get_attribute()` method. PS: nowhere do I see the use of beautiful soup. Familiarise yourself with the Webdriver API https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, i will try

Comment: As weird as it may sound , I printed the code into excel , i was missing a.text in the line "f.write(str(primary.text))" and it worked just fine, it printed everything into excel.